# Scope Issue, I cannot calculate percentage because of this.

Tags: java, scope

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Carpim {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Random myRandom = new Random(); 

    public void determine(){ 



    int trueNumber = 0; 
    int wrongNumber = 0; 
    int total = 0; 
    int answer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    int num1 = 1 + myRandom.nextInt(11);
    int num2 = 1 + myRandom.nextInt(11);
    int correctResult = num1 * num2;

    System.out.println( num1 + "*" + num2 + " What is the answer?");
    answer = input.nextInt();

    if (answer == correctResult){ 
        ++trueNumber; 
        ++total;
    }else if (answer != trueNumber){ 
        ++total; 
        ++wrongNumber; 
    }//end if statement

    }//end for loop 

    percentage(total, wrongNumber); 

    }//end method 
    private int percentage(int total, int wrongNumber){ 
        int percentage = (total - wrongNumber)/total; 

        System.out.println(total + " " + wrongNumber + " " + percentage ); 

        return percentage; 
    }//end private method. 

}//End Class
```

Here is my code, when i run this code, this cannot calculate percentage at the end. However, it can calculate wrongNumber and total numbers. Can you please help me and tell what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: what do you mean "this cannot calculate percentage"? What is the output? I would guess the issue is integer division.

Comment: your method percentage it's private that's make that inaccessible. From other classes

Comment: @Jorge:  Inside of the same class, that doesn't matter.  `private` means that only this class can use the method.

Comment: Nope, it is not the point i think, When i made it public, it gave me the same result.

Answer (score 8):

division integer with integer produces integer in java not floating point number

Answer (score 0):

First, dividing integers will produce an integer result - throwing away the decimal portion of the number.  You can fix that by changing your code to this:

```
double percentage = (double)(total - wrongNumber)/total;
```

...then returning the `double`.

Also, you're throwing away the return value of `percentage()`.  I  don't think you meant to do that, so you would want to save it in some sort of variable inside of your method, then either print or return it.

Answer (score 0):

in your percentage function, you have **int** percentage.  integer cannot contain decimal values and (total - wrongNumber) / total < 0;

Comment: Thanks man, when i converted it into double, it did work. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 0):

Your private method should be mindful of datatypes:

```
private double percentage(int total, int wrongNumber){ 
    double percentage = (double)(total - wrongNumber)/total; 

    System.out.println(total + " " + wrongNumber + " " + percentage ); 

    return percentage; 
}//end private method.
```

You should use a floating point data type to retain the decimal values in a % value.

If you want a quick way to get your percentage to 2 decimal places, you can do this:

```
double percentage = 56.4332893723;
percentage = ((int)(percentage*100))/100.0;    // instant 2-decimal conversion
```

Comment: Even if i make it public, the same result is in the console.

Comment: making it public doesn't solve the problem. The problem lies in the datatypes you are using. Notice that the datatype I am using for percentage is a double instead of an int.

Comment: int can only store whole numbers, thus your percentage's decimal values are "chopped off". you have to use a double or float data type to retain the decimal values.